# Can I take loan in my name for property in my son's name

Tags: mortgage

Can I purchase land and building taking loan from bank in my name and got the registration of the properties in my son's name and mortgage the same in the bank.

Comment: In what country? The property would be liened in the banks name, it would probably want your name on the property deed as well.

Comment: In most places that would be called identity theft.

Comment: It would probably help to explain what you are trying to accomplish with this setup.  It is hard to see why you would want the liability but not the asset unless there is something nefarious going on.  If you are merely trying to help your son, you could potentially just co-sign the loan with him (though this is generally not recommended, make sure you understand what you're getting into).

Comment: Explain the situation more.  There are several options, but depending on amounts and how you want to structure it is going to impact the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

> Can I purchase a property with a bank loan in my name, but title the property to my son?

### No.

Not as you have stated it.
The property must secure the loan (if the loan is *on the property*).

You cannot get a loan on a piece of property which you don't own - because the bank couldn't attach a lien to it in that case.
They won't give you the loan on it in that circumstance.

If that were allowed, you could:
1. get the loan
2. purchase the property titled in your son's name
3. then declare bankruptcy without making a single payment
4. and your son would be able to keep the property

### You can do one of the following:

- You can get an unsecured loan from the bank. Then you can use that money for whatever you want (including using it to purchase a property which you title in your son's name instead of yours)
- You can put both your names **on the loan** and **title it to your son** with a bank lien on the property.
- You can put both your names **on the property** with a bank lien on the property.

Comment: Your first suggestion (get an unsecured loan) directly contradicts the big "No" at the top of your answer. He could also remortgage his own house to buy a house for his son.

Comment: @RupertMorrish I see what you mean, however I took the phrase **purchase a property with a bank loan** to mean that the loan would be secured by the property. That would have a significantly lower interest rate than what he can do (which is an unsecured loan).